# Left 4 Dead 2 Special infected tips for Versus

Tags: left-4-dead-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I avoid being detected as an infected in left 4 dead 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231/how-can-i-avoid-being-detected-as-an-infected-in-left-4-dead-2)

So what are your tips for using special infected in versus?  Most of us probably know that attacking on your own as soon as you spawn usually doesn't get anywhere.

Comment: Eh?  It's different to that question, that addresses how to avoid being detected, where the answer would be, spawn at the last minute, this is a strategy guide for each class!

Comment: Hi @Tom, I think it kind of addresses the same "tips". Also, strategy guides are not exactly the kind of posts that are allowed here, please review the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). We prefer real questions looking for answers (I noticed you were starting to answer it yourself, and I assumed you were going to post an answer for each class, making it also not a question in the format allowed here) -- You can also post a question on [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/) to discuss the topic. If the question gets 5 votes to re-open, it will.

Comment: Perhaps if the question is made a little smaller in scope (ie, hunter, not all SI) and is made a little more objective like simply how to kill survivors instead of just tips, it would be better.  just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

**Spitter**

[image]

Most people spit at moving survivors, but this rarely works. Spit is most effective to:

- Spit at a fallen survivor.

If a survivor is down you get maximum damage as they can't move out the way. If other survivors are nearby, wait until they start helping them up to spit to force them to drop. This means you get maximum down time for the single survivor.

- Spit to separate survivors

If there is a room with some corridors, allow 2 survivors through then spit at the floor to block the other two. Sometimes the other two decide to wait, and the forward two carry on relentlessly and don't wait.  You then have an effective gap and your team can attack the back group all together which makes it a lot harder for survivors to cope.

- Spit at a survivor being pinned

Self explanatory!

Comment: Often spitting on a incapacitated Survivor is less effective.  The acid spit doesn't do `that` much damage while incap'd.  It's however quite effective to keep the other survivor from getting close enough to help him up.  The extra damage is just a bonus.